# Converting float to int

Tags: java

I come from Python background and taking a dive into Java world.
I am trying to convert Float to int in Java. Something we do like this in Python `int_var = int(float_var)`

`public class p1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer a = new Integer(5);
        Float b;
        b = new Float(3.14);
        a = (int)b;
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}`
Yields the following error - 

`p1.java:7: error: inconvertible types
        a = (int)b;
                 ^
  required: int
  found:    Float
1 error`

Comment: Are you aware of primitive types and their difference with their wrapper type, i.e. int vs. Integer and float vs. Float? Why are you using wrapper types instead of primitives? You shouldn't.

Comment: Okay, guess that I got confused there.

Comment: In general, never use wrapper types unless you need an Object (to be storable in a collection, for example), or a nullable primitive. Primitive types are faster and safer. There is no reason in the code you posted to use wrapper types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use primitives types, and you will be fine:

```
int a = 5;
float b = 3.14f;  // 3.14 is by default double. 3.14f is float.

a = (int)b;
```

The reason it didn't work with *Wrappers* is those types are non-covariant, and thus are incompatible.

---

And if you are using `Integer` types (Which you really don't need here), then you should not create Wrapper type objects using `new`. Just make use of *auto-boxing* feature:

```
Integer a = 5;  // instead of `new Integer(5);`
```

the above assignment works after Java 1.5, performing auto-boxing from `int` primitive to `Integer` wrapper. It also enables JVM to use cached Integer literals if available, thus preventing creation of unnecessary objects.

Comment: `float b = 3.14f`. What is the need for the `f` postfix?

Comment: Floating point literal `3.14` is by default `double`. For float, it's `3.14f`.

Comment: To make it compile. 3.14 is a double.

Comment: thus are inconvertible ... wrappers are convertable through helper functions though

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like

```
a = b.intValue()
```

Answer (score 5):

That's one of the annoying things in Java. Fix your problem with this:

```
a = (int)(float)b;
```

Unboxing will require that you cast from `Float` to `float` and then to `int`

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using boxed primitive, `a = b.intValue();` should suit your needs.

Comment: Okay this is more pythonic!

Comment: Yeah!, What I meant is that the above code is more python like, hence pythonic

Answer (score 1):

```
 float a =10.0f;
 int k=(int)a;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code
`a = b.intValue();`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.round` method:-

```
int a = Math.round(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

for the best always use:

```
Math.floor(d)
Math.round(d)
Math.abs(d)
```

These are meant for conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Use **Math.round()** as,

```
   int a = Math.round(14.32f)
```