# How can I convert a float into an int where I can?

Tags: python, floating-point

```
age = int(input('Enter your age: '))
print('How old are you?',age)
x = (.5(age)-13)
y = (.5(age)+13)
print('You can date people between', x, 'and', y)
```

I realize that age becomes a float for whatever reason. How can I modify it so that age becomes something that I can use in my given equations? I was thinking of stripping it or trying to convert it to an int?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting float to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874710/converting-float-to-int)

Comment: Is `x = (.5(age)-13)` syntactically correct? Definitely not in python 2. Did you mean `x = (.5*(age)-13)`?

Comment: Even after you correct the syntax error, the age formula can't be correct. It says a 28-year-old should be able to date a 1-year-old. The rule I've heard is half your age plus 7, or plus 2 if you're famous or rich See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_disparity_in_sexual_relationships#The_"half-your-age-plus-seven"_rule.

Answer (score 4):

age is an int, multiplying it by 0.5 give a float result, use //2 to obtain the quotient (*0.5 is equivalent to /2)

```
age = int(input('Enter your age: '))
print('How old are you?',age)
x = age//2-13
y = age//2+13
print('You can date people between', x, 'and', y)
```